# How to get time between intervals of an on/off sequence?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, html5-canvas, morse-code

I'm a bit of an amateur coder, so I'll explain my issue to the best of my ability:

I'm trying to create a Morse Code Light Decoder, with the input being a video of a flashing morse code sequence, and the output being the decoded phrase.

So far, I have gotten a variable that is true when the light is on, and false when it is off.
Here is a video of what I have so far: 
[Demo Video](https://streamable.com/ibzxaa) 
And here is my program if you want to edit it: 
[Morse Decoder](https://codepen.io/artsydude/pen/jOmNwBo) 
Here is the video I am using for testing: 
[Test](https://streamable.com/idpt7b)

What I'm looking for is to somehow convert the fluctuating variable in the top left to something that looks like this:

```
[{"state":"on", "lengthtime":"300ms"}, {"state":"off", "lengthtime":"200ms"}, {"state":"on", "lengthtime":"400ms"}, ...]
```

This list is each pulse/pause in order, along with the length of each pulse/pause. This would be easy to parse through and convert to morse.

Code that I check if its on or off:

```
function drawFrame(video) {
  let onoff = 0;

  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  grayscaleVid(imageData.data);
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  var pixel = context.getImageData(112, 64, 1, 1);
  var data = pixel.data;
  const brightness = (data[0] + data[1] + data[2]) / 3;

  if (brightness > 130) {
    onoff = true;
  } else {
    onoff = false;
  }
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = onoff;

  setTimeout(function() {
    drawFrame(video);
  }, 10);
}
```

Comment: the code is deleted ... please add the code to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry, fixed it.

Comment: can you show the code that displays the value true/false at the top?

Comment: @iagowp it’s in the file, but here’s that part: if (brightness > 130) {
        onoff = true;
      } else {
        onoff = false;
      }
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = onoff;

Comment: I'm not going to download a file from elsewhere. When asking a question, you should try to have the relevant code to the question on the question itself, so it can remain useful in the future. As it is right now, you could delete that code from your Drive and this question would be useless for other people

Comment: And also, how do you run that if code? How often does it run? What triggers it

Comment: @iagowp the code is transferring each video frame to a canvas element by running function drawFrame(video). This code is right before the end of the function.

Comment: Again, I'm not downloading it. The code relevant to that should be on the question

Comment: @iagowp changed it to a codepen link

Answer (score 1):

Set up some global storage with a history and a previous state:

```
const history = [];
let wasOn = False;
```

Adjust the brightness detection to log to `history`

```js
const isOn = brightness > 130;

if (wasOn != isOn) {
  history.push({
    state: wasOn,
    timestamp: performance.now(),
  });
  wasOn = isOn;
}
```

Then, when done, process the results:

```
const results = history.map((v,i,a) => {
  if (!i) return {state: v.state, duration: 0};
  return {state: v.state, duration: v.timestamp - a[i-1].timestamp};
});
```

Comment: append? Do you mean push?

Comment: I used this, and it worked. The only problem is that when you open a new window/tab and have it running in the background, it starts messing up. Do you know why? Here's what I have: https://codepen.io/artsydude/pen/OJmNymV

Comment: Background tabs in modern browsers are throttled and so do not update in real time. Video isn't updated and javascript events are handled at a reduced rate. `setTimeout()` especially is effected by this as its timing is only guaranteed to be greater than or equal to the requested delay. `.requestAnimationFrame()` is also effected as background tabs are updated infrequently.

Comment: @Ouroborus is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Not sure. The way to fix `setTimeout()` would be to run it in a Web Worker context. However, I'm pretty sure you can't process video normally in that context because there's no DOM and no way to create elements. You could, of course, handle it on the server side though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you need to do is, create a timer, and every time the state changes from on to off, or vice-versa, create a new register.

```
let registers = []
;
let currTime = Date.now();
let onoff = false;

function drawFrame(){
  ...
  let newOnoff;
  if (brightness > 130) {
    newOnoff = true;
  } else {
    newOnoff = false;
  }

  if (newOnoff !== onoff) {
    const state = onoff === true ? 'on' : 'off';
    const newTime = Date.now();
    registers.push({state, lengthtime : (newTime - currTime) + 'ms' });
    currTime = newTime;
  }

  onoff = newOnoff;
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = onoff;
  
  ...
}
```

This code is not really pretty, but I'm just keeping the standards you're using